# Calling API only once on changing segments

Tags: swift, ios, rx-swift

I am working on a screen which has segmented control and has 3 segments (year value 2019, 18, 17) and what I am doing is that on each segment click I have to reload data inside a tableview (getting data from an API request).

```
let purchaseResponse = inputs.selectedTab.map { index -> String in
        switch index {
        case 0:
            return "2019"
        case 1:
            return "2018"
        case 2:
            return "2017"
        default:
            return "2019"
        } }
        .distinct()
        .flatMapLatest { year in
            return purchaseService.fetchPurchaseHistory(forYear: year, pageNumber: 1)
        }
        .trackActivity(inputs.indicator)
        .materialize()
        .share()
```

Right now this is what I have, and it works fine, as you can see I am using the `Distinct` operator which is like this:

```
extension Observable where Element: Hashable {

func distinct() -> Observable<Element> {
    var set = Set<Element>()
    return flatMap { element -> Observable<Element> in
        objc_sync_enter(self); defer {objc_sync_exit(self)}
        if set.contains(element) {
            return Observable<Element>.empty()
        } else {
            set.insert(element)
            return Observable<Element>.just(element)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Can I somehow refactor this, or maybe use builtin operators? The reason to use `Distinct` was that if the user clicks a segment, next time it shouldn't get data from the API.

Answer (score 1):

The operator you are looking for is [distinctUntilChanged()](https://rxmarbles.com/#distinctUntilChanged). It skips only equal items followed one by one.

Or [distinct()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html) operator which skips the items what has been even once emitted in the sequence. In your case the `fetchPurchaseHistory` method could be triggered no more than 3 times by this observable with `distinct` operator